Cannot build graph boost library from source
I am trying to build Boost from source using emscripten.
One executable CMake project I have has a dependency on the following boost libraries:

Boost::boost
Boost::filesystem
Boost::program_options
Boost::graph

So I am building the requested boost libraries using the following commands:
git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git --branch boost-1.85.0
cd boost 
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 --show-libraries
  <Here, I see graph is indeed listed, so are filesystem and program_options>
./b2 toolset=emscripten link=static variant=release threading=multi runtime-link=static filesystem program_options graph

This last command exits with the following error:
don't know how to make <e>graph
...found 1 target...
...can't find 1 target...

If I omit graph from the build, boost builds fine. Why can't I just build graph just like I can build filesystem, system and other libraries?
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 from within a WSL environment, not sure if that matters.

So, I wanted to try this out. On my nix-setup I made an empty directory emscripten_projects with default.nix:
{pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}}:
pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "emscripten boost shell";

  nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [
    pkg-config
    cmake
    emscripten
  ];

  env = {
    EM_CACHE = "/home/sehe/.emscripten_cache";
    Boost_DIR = "/home/sehe/custom/emscripten_projects/emboost/stage/lib/cmake";
  };

  shellHook = ''
    echo "Setting up emscripten cache in $EM_CACHE"
    rsync -hxDa "${pkgs.emscripten}/share/emscripten/cache/" "$EM_CACHE"
    chmod u+rwX -R "$EM_CACHE"
  '';
}

This tiny shell definition installs cmake and emscripten. The most of the work is to avoid permission errors on the emscripten cache (see here).
Next up, I built stuff like this:
git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git --branch boost-1.85.0 --depth=1 emboost --jobs=16
cd emboost
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 toolset=emscripten --with-graph

This all builds like clockwork: (fullres mp4 here, 69MiB)

Demo Program
Let's compile a demo, main.cpp:
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

struct Vertex {
  int id;
};

using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Vertex>;

int main() {
    G g;
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", get(&Vertex::id, g));

    std::istringstream dot(R"(digraph G {
        0;
        1;
        2;
        0 -> 1;
        1 -> 2;
        2 -> 0;
    })");

    read_graphviz(dot, g, dp);

    print_graph(g, get(&Vertex::id, g));
}

This specifically uses the linked-library feature read_graphviz because it is NOT header-only:


Thank you! I only remembered the old-style syntax, using "b2 ... components". The syntax with the "--with-" specification is new to me and changes everything. I now get the 'stage/lib' folder created - I didn't before (even without graph this folder should have been created)

Yeah. Leaving the --with-graph option will also build the graph library but also many libraries not relevant for this answer, I only had it to save time (like the shallow got clone). For what it's worth I never specify components though. Instead I basically say ./b2 only adding a parameter when I really need to override something

I believe I found the solution, by replacing graph with headers.
The graph folder does seem to be available now under the boost subfolder, unfortunately I can't check if it really works because now I have another problem related to emscripten.

That's not building the library. You just get header-only parts.
